# javaFx Label wrapText doesn't work

Tags: java, javafx

I am new developer and I try to make a program. in my program there is a list of messages (`listMessages`) and each message in it is a `MessageItemController` which I created (a custom control) with a `VBox` in it that contains a label and some other things. Sudo code of that `VBox` in `MessageItemController`:

```
<VBox fx:id="VBoxContent" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="1" GridPane.vgrow="ALWAYS">
        <children>
            <Label fx:id="lblMessage" text="message" textOverrun="CLIP" wrapText="true">
                <padding>
                    <Insets left="10.0" />
                </padding>
            </Label>
           ...
        </children>
    </VBox>
```

I want to `VBoxContent` has a maximum width. before, I set a `MaxWidth` for my `VBoxContent`to for example 300px. (I do this in scenebuilder and my fxml file not with code). It's work perfectly. all my message which I add to my `listMessages` work.
Now I changed my idea and I want `MessageItemController` to has maxWidth but 0.5 percent of its parent (I mean `listMessages` which I add this messages to them). so I remove `maxWidth` from my fxml file and add this code in my controller:

```
listMessages.widthProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
        if (observableListMessages != null)
            observableListMessages.forEach(x -> {
                x.VBoxContent.setMaxWidth(0.5 * newValue.doubleValue());                    
            });
    });
```

but maybe `wrapText` of label doesn't work if I set `MaxWidth` (or even `PrefWidth`) for my `VBox` from code (not fxml).
Is it possible to help my problem? If you can say how can I make text wrap or if it is not possible and it is problem of javafx so if there is any idea to achieve my purpose, please say it.
I'm sorry for bad English. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to set the `prefWidth` for the `Label` itself.

Here is a short demo application:

```
public class Main extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        VBox root = new VBox(5);
        root.setPadding(new Insets(10));

        Label label = new Label("This is some long text that should be wrapped.");
        label.setWrapText(true);
        label.setPrefWidth(100);

        root.getChildren().add(label);

        primaryStage.setWidth(200);
        primaryStage.setHeight(200);

        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root));

        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

Until you set the preferred width for your `Label`, it doesn't really know where you want to start wrapping.

If you want the label to wrap with the size of your `VBox`, you could bind the `PrefWidthProperty` of your `Label` to the `WidthProperty` of the `VBox` instead:

```
label.prefWidthProperty().bind(root.widthProperty());
```

Doing this will allow your text to fill the width of its container, but wrap if it's too long.

Comment: thanks for answer. at first I think that is not work but It worked. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Wrap your text in a thing called `TextFlow` in your FXML. It will save you so much headaches.

Comment: The only solution that worked for me. I still had to add `label.setWrapText(true)` and `label.prefWidthProperty().bind`.